# Magento 2 - Events

Tags: magento2, event-observer

whats the difference if I place events.xml directly under etc folder , under etc/frontend or etc/adminhtml ?

Suppose I want to capture an event `sales_quote_collect_totals_after` on both admin & frontend, should I create events.xml in both frontend & adminhtml folders and write the code in both files ?

Or I can just write in the global one and it will work for both ?

Answer (score 2):

There are not only frontend and backend areas, but also e.g. webapi_rest, webapi_soap. If you define event in the global area, this event will be available for all areas.

Create global event.xml for general cases, unless you want to exclude some specific areas.